# Is it possible to have multiple promises returned by a single factory?

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('mymodule', [
])
  .controller('myController', [
      '$scope', 'myModel'
      function($scope, myModel) {
          // Some code here

      }
  ]);
  .factory('myModel', [
      '$scope',
      function($scope) {
          // Some code here

      }
  ]);
```

then in your routing file

```
$routeProvider.when('/someroute', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/someroute.html', 
    resolve: ['myModel'] //ALWAYS IN ARRAY)
});
```

In this code you have one resolve method in myModel. Is there a way to add a second method to myModel so you can add a second 'when' with another revolve function using the same model?

edit:
I added some methods(getOrder) to the factory but now don't know how to call a specifik method:

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
  when('/order/:id', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/order/Order.html',
                        controller: "test.controller.order.Order",
                        resolve: {
                            getOrder: ["test.resolver.Order", function (resolveProvider) {
                                return resolveProvider().getOrder();
                            }
                            ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right,  It should be something like:

```
myModule.factory('ajax_post', ['$http',  function(_http) {   

    return{
        TypeOne: function(jsonData){
            var _promise= _http.post(/**/ );            
            return _promise; 
        },       
        TypeTwo: function(uploadedFile){

            var upload_promise =  _http.post(/**/);

            return upload_promise;
        },
        TypeThree: function(uploadedFile){

            var upload_promise =  _http.post(/**/);

            return upload_promise;
        }     
    }   
 }]);
```

In my example I use the same `factory` with 3 types of `promise`:

- init
- uploadFile_init
- uploadFile_init_for_compare

  ```
  myModule.factory('ajax_post', ['$http',  function(_http) {   

  var path = 'src/php/data.ajax.php';

  return{
      init: function(jsonData){
          var _promise= _http.post(path, 
              jsonData
              ,{
                  headers: {
                      'SOAPActions': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems'
                  }
              }
              );            
          return _promise; 
      },       
      uploadFile_init: function(uploadedFile){
          var fd = new FormData();
          fd.append("uploadedFile", uploadedFile);
          var upload_promise =  _http.post("src/php/data.ajax.php",
              fd,
              {
                  headers:{
                      'Content-Type':undefined
                  },
                  transformRequest:angular.identity
              });

          return upload_promise;
      },
      uploadFile_init_for_compare: function(uploadedFile){
          var fd = new FormData();
          fd.append("uploadedFileForCompare", uploadedFile);
          var upload_promise =  _http.post("src/php/data.ajax.php",
              fd,
              {
                  headers:{
                      'Content-Type':undefined
                  },
                  transformRequest:angular.identity
              });

          return upload_promise;
      }
  ```

  }
  }]);

From controller you can call it as:

```
var promise_1 = ajax_post.init(someJsonData);
var promise_2 = ajax_post.uploadFile_init(someJsonData)
var promise_3 = ajax_post.uploadFile_init_for_compare(someJsonData);
```